# How to restrict folder access to only subdomain redirect?

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, subdomain, apache2

I want to redirect a subdomain to a folder such that the only way to access that folder is by the subdomain.

```
app.example.com => example.com/app
example.com/app => 404 Not Found
```

Is this possible by a combination of DNS record and .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using redirects but separated each subdomain into its own virtual host, with a separate root folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app1/
  ServerName app1.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/app2/
  ServerName app2.example.com
</VirtualHost>

...
```